# typerror in python while adding value to keys

Tags: python

This is what I am trying to go for but i keep getting error any ideas?

```
third_value_list =[0,1] 
for i in third_value_list 
num_list = [1,2] 
val_list = [0,1] 
dict1 = dict((k, [v]+i) for (k, v) in zip(num_list,val_list)) 
print dict1
```

TypeError:can only concatenate list (not 'int') to list

desired output 
{1:[0,0],2:[1,0],1:[0,1],2:[1,1]}

Comment: What is the purpose of the `third_value_list` that you're looping on? If it had multiple values, what would you expect your code to do?

Comment: What do you think `[v]+i` is going to do? Break that second-to-last line into several statements to get a clearer understanding of what part is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a a value to key in your dictionary just make sure the values are, from the start, tuples or lists. Once you do this you can just:

```
    d = {1:(0,),2:(0,)}
    d[1] = d[1]+(0,)
```

And a new value is now present at d[1]. Other than that and you might have to build a function to handle the difference between types (list, tuple, int, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to construct, but you can get the desired result simply by

```
num_list = [1,2]
val_list = [0,1]
dict1 = dict((k, [v, 0]) for (k, v) in zip(num_list,val_list))
```

The main problem in your code is that you are trying to add a list and an integer

```
[v]+i
```

which I replaced with `[v,i]`. But since `i` is always 0 you get the answer I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will never be able to get an output like that because you can not have duplicate keys in a dictionary. Assigning a value to an existing key will wipe out the old value.

Answer (score 0):

I add [] and i got the desired output yes it is possible

```
third_value_list =[0,1] 
for i in third_value_list 
num_list = [1,2] 
val_list = [0,1] 
dict1 = dict((k, [v]+[i]) for (k, v) in zip(num_list,val_list)) 
print dict1
```